# How to get the latest IMDbPY in 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04, installation, apt, python

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I would like to install the latest [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) because the one in the repository has a bug with the country codes. This bug has been fixed in the later versions, but I don't know how to install the latest version. I don't have experience in installing python modules/packaes which are not in apt-get.

Can you tell me how can I either **install the latest version from source** or use a newer repository for this package?

I would prefer to install from source, as current version now is 4.8.2 and the newest one in the later repositories is still only 4.7.1.

I installed python-setuptools and now when I try to run:

```
sudo easy_install IMDbPY
```

it returns:

```
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:54:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c: In function ‘strings_check’:
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:74: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:74: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:82: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strcmp’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c: In function ‘ratcliff’:
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:152: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c: In function ‘strtolower’:
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:164: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:164: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘tolower’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c: At top level:
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:169: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:207: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:254: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cutils_methods’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c: In function ‘initcutils’:
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:266: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_InitModule’
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:266: error: ‘cutils_methods’ undeclared (first use in this function)
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:266: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
imdb/parser/sql/cutils.c:266: error: for each function it appears in.)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing `python-dev`. But yes, grabbing the deb from Debian unstable is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

OP answered the question in a comment

> Luckily I found a 4.8.2.deb from unstable debian and I could install that. It seems to work well so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all there is to do is extract the archive and run the `setup.py` script as shown below. Provided all dependencies are satisfied, it should work.

```
python ./setup.py
```

Comment: It had problems just like the easy_install. Luckily I found a 4.8.2.deb from unstable debian and I could install that. It seems to work well so far.